# NoSQL, how to make "complex" query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

If I created the following NoSQL table using DynamoDB, how might I query for the item with the largest `ID` value whose `Unused` value is `true` without scanning the entire table?

*(I have zero experience with cloud platforms and NoSQL.)*

```
+--------+------------+-----------+
|   ID   |   Unused   |   Token   |
+--------+------------+-----------+
|    1   |   True     |   ...     |
+--------+------------+-----------+
|    2   |   True     |   ...     |
+--------+------------+-----------+
|    3   |   True     |   ...     |
+--------+------------+-----------+
|    4   |   False    |   ...     |
+--------+------------+-----------+
|    5   |   False    |   ...     |
+--------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Try  -- Select * from c where c.Unused = True ;

Comment: @amitagarwal that looks like an SQL statement?

Comment: Yes , but NoSql do have option of Querying thats why it has Sql in it.

Comment: which programming language you are using to query ? There are few docs available on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.ReadData.Query.html

Comment: @amitagarwal nosql so dynamodb. ive edited the Q too. i forgot to put "without scanning"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) with `Unused` as the partition key and `Id` as the sort key.

| Unused | ID | Token |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | 1 | --- |
| True | 2 | --- |
| True | 3 | --- |
| False | 4 | --- |
| False | 5 | --- |

Using a Query you can do the following:
`SELECT * FROM mytable.myindex WHERE Unused='True' LIMIT 1 DESC`

[This blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/effective-data-sorting-with-amazon-dynamodb/) will help you to understand the pros and cons.

Comment: perfect. tysm for explaining this to me. ofc the query that you wrote `SELECT * FROM mytable.myindex WHERE Unused='True' LIMIT 1 DESC` will look quite a bit different from that `MySQL` syntax, right? going to bed now so ill read that doc u provided as soon as i wake up tomo

Comment: Given the context in the OPs other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78138676/dynamodb-or-rds) I'm not sure this will really fit his needs since a GSI is always eventually consistent.

Comment: You can use the syntax exactly as I wrote it, using the PartiQL API. Check it out: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.html

Comment: thx leeeeeeeroy jenkins

Comment: would u be open to hopping in a chat for 5 minutes so i can pick ur brain and ask u a couple quesitons about RDS vs DynamoDB?

Comment: @Charles what does it mean that "GSI is always eventually consistent"? also, i heard that including GSI doubles the cost of a read/write, is this true? (sorry, i missed your comment before)

Comment: With DDB you can request a [strongly consistent read](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html) of a table.  That is not an option for a GSI.

Comment: Leeroy, if i restructure the table so that `Unused` is the partition key and `ID` is the sort key (so that i dont need to use a GSI) and then `SELECT * FROM mytable.myindex WHERE Unused='True' LIMIT 1 DESC`, how many reads or RRUs would that constitute?

Comment: 0.5 RRU for eventually consistent.

Comment: ok cool thx! i thought maybe because `Unused` would be the partition key and thus create an item collection that it would charge me for "scanning" that collection to ultimately read the 1 row

Comment: As long as your evaluation is in the KeyConditionExpression you'll be efficient. Things become inefficient when you use FilterExpression.

Comment: sorry to keep bugging you. would using `Unused` as the pk and `ID` as the sk in a table with, say, 500k-1m items, cause issues (e.g. "hot partition")?

Comment: im messing around in the partiql editor and looking at the documentation now, not sure it partiql supports `LIMIT 1` -.-a [or it seems the value of `LIMIT` determines how many items to "evaluate" as opposed to what is returned](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ExecuteStatement.html#API_ExecuteStatement_RequestSyntax#DDB-ExecuteStatement-request-Limit)? not sure why it is not working in the playground editor tho

Comment: PartiQL supports `Limit` but not part of the `Statement`. The PartiQL editor only gives you access to the `Statement` which means it does not support `Limit`. The API does however support it.

Comment: thanks! and `LIMIT` only determines how many items to scan (as opposed to how many items to return), right? or am i misunderstanding that part?

Comment: That's correct. But if are accessing items based on keys then you will be returned exactly what you want. If you use a FilterExpression you could get returned less